# Старт на Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Здравствуйте, уважаемые пользователи, подскажите, пожалуйста, что почитать по Ruby? (Что-нибудь на русском языке.) Не зная основ Ruby, сразу начинать с RoR, сложно?

Comment: Вот такой же вопрос: http://hashcode.ru/questions/83279/web-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-ruby-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-c-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 3):

Я читал вот эту книгу: [программирование на языке Ruby](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3411405/). Не могу сказать, какова она в сравнении с другими, поскольку других не читал. Но она даёт полное представление о возможностях самого языка. Это факт.

Answer (score 3):

Начать с RoR не сложно, если есть опыт, но это не правильно идеологически, начинать изучение языка с фреймворка.
И привыкайте к англоязычной литературе

Comment: Знания английского у меня нулевые, именно по этому попросил на русском.

Comment: имел ввиду, что к этому надо стремиться

Comment: Совет насчёт литературы - не самый удачный с точки зрения построения русскоязычного IT-сообщества. Безусловно, англоязычная литература исключительно полезна в ситуации, когда русскоязычная отсутствует. Однако если все привыкнут к англоязычной, то русскоязычная так никогда и не появится. На неё просто не будет спроса.

Comment: есть смысл в Ваших словах, но поймите, я тоже не из прихоти этот совет написал, просто ситуация на данный момент такова, что без английского никуда, просто это факт и не важно нравится он кому или нет.

Comment: Я прекрасно понял, что вы имели в виду. Потому и сделал уточнение насчёт русскоязычного сообщества. Вы правильно говорите, что на данный момент ситуация такова, что без английского сложно. Однако ваш совет изучать английский лишь способствует её закреплению.

Comment: Не сочтите за рекламу, пока искал литературу и уроки,наткнулся на такой замечательный скринкаст - http://ruby.hasbrains.ru/. Может кому пригодится.

Answer (score 2):

Вот эта ([язык программирования Ruby](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5704300/)) хорошая (один из авторов - Мацумото - создатель языка). После неё можно и за RoR.

Answer (score 1):

Держи [RubyScreencastsRu's channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/RubyScreencastsRu)  :)
Я думаю, это лучше всего Вам подойдёт!

Answer (score 0):

Если есть хоть небольшие зачатки английского, можно посмотреть ещё [это](http://tryruby.org/).

Answer (score 0):

не плохая книга [Гибкая разработка веб-приложений в среде Rails](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/8153111/) один из соавторов Дэвид Хэнссон создатель технологии Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить о Rails без знания Ruby, то, думаю, очень хорошим вариантом для начала будет книга [Майкла Хартла](http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/4_0/beginning) - хороший ввод для TDD, git, деплой сразу на Heroku. В общем, сразу разговор идёт о Rails в привязке к хорошему стеку технологий.
Дал ссылку на перевод книги на русский язык - эта версия книги отстаёт немного, но не думаю, что это будет критичным.

Но а вообще, как и писали выше, без английского с RoR никуда. Советую английскому выделять, для начала, не меньше времени, чем языкам программирования.
Объясню чуть подробнее. Когда я начал изучать программирование, я тоже не знал английского. Имена методов приходилось попросту заучивать, но суть-то в том, что в самих названиях методов есть подсказки к тому, что тот или иной метод делает (например, если знать, что 'empty' = 'пустой', то не будет возникать вопросов в том, что делает метод array.empty?, и, наоборот, не будет возникать вопроса, как проверить то, что массив пустой). Плюс, хоть и открылся русский stackoverflow, но правильно составленный поисковой запрос на английском почти точно приведёт либо на страницу документации с ответом на вопрос, либо на вопрос на SOF (англоязычный), который, как минимум, очень похож на введённый тобой вопрос.

Потому ещё вопрос - английского нет вообще, или он есть, но слабый? Если он есть, просто слабый, советую как можно быстрее начать пользоваться англоязычными ресурсами.